# Incorrect Album and Attribution in Windows Media Player

Tags: audio-recording, daw, mp3, media, creative-commons

After exporting an audio mixdown from DAW to (WMA or MP3) and editing applicable tags with appropriate software, Media Player in Windows 10 often still gets album, artist and other attribution information incorrect on playback.

Windows Media Player might correctly pick up the main artist, title, composers and/or producers from the mixdown and MP3 Tag editing, but it then apparently seems to guess to try to fill in the blanks for some tags.

This is frustrating because it makes the producer and artists look like they have ripped someone else's music off which is not at all the case. Instead, the producer and artists unfortunately picked a title (by accident) that is potentially similar to other much better known works of art.

How can a producer and/or content creator ensure she/he gets correct attribution for his/or audio mixdowns when they are played back in Windows Media Player and other similar tools that try to pull album information off the internet?

NOTEs: Other formats like OGG might also be okay, but I don't think support for OGG is as ubiquitous as it is for WMA/MP3.  Also, I suppose DRM is an option for enforcing correct attribution, but amateur artists/producers with day jobs might find it difficult to get started with DRM.  Finally, DRM is incompatible with all Creative Commons licenses:
https://creativecommons.org/2017/07/09/terrible-horrible-no-good-bad-drm/

Comment: If you're releasing brand new songs, it's up to you or the record company to report them correctly to [CDDB/Gracenote](https://www.gracenote.com), then consumer auto-fetch structures should get the correct match. Long, long time since I've done it, so idk how the system works these days.

Comment: BTW, this should be done as part of the standard cataloguing tasks, registering the titles  with PRS, PPL, MCPS [or your country's equivalent] to ensure your authors & composers , artists, co-contributors, record company, distributors & publishers each get the correct shares on reported usages/mechanicals. [This is a task I've never had to do myself - I used to always have a record company to do it, these days I pay an independent label to handle it. It's complicated.]